# Is there a way to determine the URL where a particular Visualforce page is being used in an org?

Tags: visualforce

I know there's the Preview URL that's available from the Setup > Visualforce Pages screen. But I have many VF pages that use variable data and standard controllers and would like to view those VF pages in context.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a simple way to do what you're asking without writing some code to search your visualforce pages and related controllers to find the information you'll need. I say that because if you go to the VisualForce page's properties in Setup, you can click on "Where is is used?" to see where a page is called from. You can also click on "Dependencies" find related classes that must be present for it to run.

The methods in the Controllers for the referring pages that call a page will determine what the final pageReference will look like. Don't forget that the final url will also likely be parameter and recordId specific (depends on the design of the page).

What you're asking for is not a trivial matter to determine. I would expect creating a script to collect this information would be the most appropriate way to successfully compile the information you're looking for *if you want this task to be automated for you.